# Bitmask grouping using SQLite

Tags: sqlite, select, group-by, bitmask

I have an sqlite table when each table has a field which I use to hold some bitmask enum.

I would like to perform a query which will return me all results and group all enums into one field:

Services: TEXT name,INTEGER service,INTEGER mask

```
SELECT service,XXX FROM Services GROUP BY service
```

Basically, I would like XXX to be the result of bitmask OR (|) of all masks per that service.

Data:

```
'a1',1,1
'a2',1,2,
'a3',1,4,
'a4',1,8,

'b1',2,1,
'b2',2,3,
'b3',2,2
```

So as a result, I would like to get the following rows:

```
1,15 (1|2|4|8)
2,3 (1|3|2)
```

Thanks

**EDIT:**
In my original question, I've forgot to mention that each mask is not a single bit but can be a mask of multiple bits (I've changed the second example to reflect that).

Comment: I think in your example you meant the results to show 2,3 as it's a (1|2|2) based on your example

Comment: you are right - thanks. I've fixed that.

Comment: Do you know all the possible bitmap mask values ahead of time that you will use? i.e. 1, 2, 4, ... 4096?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SQLite supports custom aggregate functions; depending on your set up you could [register a custom function](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/create_function.html) to do this pretty easily. Using the C API:

```
void bitwise_or_step(sqlite3_context *context, int argc, sqlite3_value** argv)
{
    int *buffer = (int *)sqlite3_aggregate_context(context, sizeof(int));
    int x = sqlite3_value_int(argv[0]);
    *buffer |= x;
}

void bitwise_or_final(sqlite3_context *context)
{
    int *buffer = (int *)sqlite3_aggregate_context(context, sizeof(int));
    sqlite3_result_int(context, *buffer);
}

sqlite3_create_function_v2(db, "BITWISE_OR", 1, SQLITE_ANY, NULL,
    NULL, bitwise_or_step, bitwise_or_final, NULL);
```

Then within your SQL, you should be able to do:

```
SELECT service,BITWISE_OR(mask) FROM Services GROUP BY service
```

If you're using PHP, you can [define a custom aggregate function from PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/sqlite3.createaggregate.php), too.

Answer (score 3):

A bitmask OR (|) operation of integers in SQL is simple matter of summing up unique power of 2 values for each key:

```
todd$ sqlite3 ex1
SQLite version 3.7.5
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sqlite> create table Services(Name varchar(100), Service int, mask int);
sqlite> insert into Services values("a1", 1, 1);
sqlite> insert into Services values("a2", 1, 2);
sqlite> insert into Services values("a3", 1, 4);
sqlite> insert into Services values("a4", 1, 8);
sqlite> insert into Services values("b1", 2, 1);
sqlite> insert into Services values("b2", 2, 3);
sqlite> insert into Services values("b3", 2, 2);
sqlite> select * from Services;
a1|1|1
a2|1|2
a3|1|4
a4|1|8
b1|2|1
b2|2|3
b3|2|2
```

EDIT: When you know the bitmap domain, you can bitand the value into its parts and sum:

```
sqlite> select Service, max(mask&1) + max(mask&2) +  max(mask&4) + max(mask&8) from Services group by Service;
1|15
2|3
sqlite>
```

You can extend the max(mask&*bit*) logic for all know powers of 2 you are storing in the bitmap mask.

Comment: thanks, but when my mask is 7 for example, this solution won't work

Comment: @Gilad 7 is not a power of 2 so I am not following your logic. The assumption based on your dataset is that each row would contain a single bitmap value per row. You can still use a SQL only approach when a row has a combined bitmap, but it is more elaborate with bitand checking et al. Need a better sample data set to illustrate.

Comment: thank you for the example. your solution can indeed work with SQL only, but in my application I've preferred to register a custom function (as per @benzado suggestion) since eventually it makes the SQL query shorter and more readable.

Comment: @Gilad no worries; the SQL only approach works for other database as well since I used the concept in an Oracle solution years ago for applying a security model with roles being the bitmap.